# Capybara have_text Passes When It Should Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I have an test written with RSpec and Capybara that should not be passing, however it is:

```
it 'should have the given text' do
  visit root_path
  expect(page).to have_text("This is not here")
end
```

I then included this in the test to look for the issue:

```
puts page.text
```

It returns a lot more text than is on the page, and included in that is:

```
Extracted source (around line #12):
10 11 12 13
})
visit root_path
expect(page).to have_text("This is not here")
```

It looks like whatever I put in my test will come up when it calls `has_text?`.  Why does it contain all this text that is not on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have an error in your app/code and a gem rendering the error, and surrounding code, to the returned page enabled in test mode.  You want to disable all those types of gems (`better_errors`, etc) when in test mode (so it's closer to production mode). You can do that by moving them to a development only group in your Gemfile. You can also look in `test.log` to see what error is being thrown.